# Using grep on a 'live' file in Windows

Tags: c#, java, powershell, grep, live

I have no idea if what I am trying to do is doable, I'm hoping to get some ideas from all the gurus out there.

First problem is I can't use Linux, since it is a live file and it resides on a Windows server.

Second problem I do not want to start from the beginning of the file every time I do grep, this is because the file has millions of lines, so I need to stop at a line x and next time I do a search I want it to start from line x.

I'm thinking about writing a PowerShell script, c# code or Java code. I am open to all solutions but I am not sure how to use grep using either of those languages in Windows.

Any ideas will help.

Thanks

**Edit**

I found this library https://code.google.com/p/grep4j/
I am going to try it and I will post if it its good or not

Comment: You can install mingw to get a nice set of unix command-line tools on your windows machine

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin/). And execute 'grep' from there...

HIH